# Why assuming that the ideal in Minkowski's bound is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Minkowski’s bound states that given a quadratic field $K(\sqrt{d})$ then every class of ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ contains an integral ideal of norm<$\lambda(d)$.
Then my notes say that this integral ideal may assumed to be prime but I fail to see why. To me this is saying that if $I$ is an ideal that is not prime nor principal then there is a principal ideal $(a)$ such that $I+(a)$ is prime. Can anyone explain me why such a result should hold?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @skmehta can you elaborate a little?  What do you mean *the* maximal ideal containg $I$?

Comment: @skmehta surely this is not true.  Take a maximal ideal that generates a cyclic class group of order, say, 3.  Then its square is an integral ideal in a different ideal class than the original.

Comment: @skmehta I just read your claim $I=JK$; you should review the definition of ideal class, what you are claiming is different than two ideals being in the same ideal class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each ideal class in ${\mathbb Q}(i)$ contains an ideal with norm $< 2$, and the only such ideal is $(1)$, which isn't prime.

It is true that every ideal class contains a prime ideal (even infinitely many),
but I doubt that this follows from Minkowski's work. This claim is a special case of a generalization of Dirichlet's prime number theorem to number fields and requires the existence of the Hilbert class field.

Comment: Can you justify why every ideal class has a prime ideal?  All the notes I have on algebraic number theory simply state this as a fact without justification (and use it in computations to compute class groups) so I guess it must be easy to show.

Comment: I'm surprised that it is used in class group calculations - are you sure? Or do you use the much simpler claim that the class group is generated by prime ideals?

Comment: Perhaps not; perhaps the only thing they are doing is using prime ideals of small norm to construct other ideals of small norm that will be inside each class.  Returning to the question of prime ideals in each class, the only way I can justify the claim is using both Artin reciprocity to go from class group to the Galois group of the Hilbert class field, and Cebotarev density to ensure many primes becoming Frobenius for each Galois element (I am talking about abelian extensions).  Which special cases of these two are enough to give this?

Comment: The theorem about prime ideals in each ideal class was proved by Weber using only the existence of the Hilbert class field; it must have been around 1900, long before Artin and Chebotarev. The existence of the Hilbert class field implies the nonvanishing of the associated L-series, and that's all you need.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I will look this up.